# Single line comment continuation

Tags: c++, comments

From the C++ standard (going back to at least C++98) § 2.2, note 2 states:

> Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. Except for splices reverted in a raw string literal, if a splice results in a character sequence that matches the syntax of a universal-character-name, the behavior is undeﬁned. A source ﬁle that is not empty and that does not end in a new-line character, or that ends in a new-line character immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place, shall be processed as if an additional new-line character were appended to the ﬁle.

And, section § 2.7 states:

> The characters /* start a comment, which terminates with the characters */. These comments do not nest. The characters // start a comment, which terminates with the next new-line character. If there is a form-feed or a vertical-tab character in such a comment, only white-space characters shall appear between it and the new-line that terminates the comment; no diagnostic is required. [Note: The comment characters //, /*, and */ have no special meaning within a // comment and are treated just like other characters. Similarly, the comment characters // and /* have no special meaning within a /* comment. ]

I would take these two together to mean that the following:

```
// My comment \
is valid

// My comment \ still valid \
is valid
```

are legal in C++98. In GCC 4.9.2, these both compile without any diagnostic messages. In MSVC 2013, these both produce the following:

```
warning C4010: single-line comment contains line-continuation character
```

If you have warnings as errors enabled (which, I do), this causes the program to not compile successfully (without warnings-as-errors, it works just fine). Is there something in the standard that disallows single-line comment continuations, or is this a case of MSVC non-compliance with the standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it's MS being sensitive to the fact that if you do something like:

```
#define macro() \
    some stuff \
    // Intended as comment \
    more stuff
```

then you get VERY interesting errors when you use `macro()` in the code.

Or other simply accidentally typing a comment like this:

```
// The files for foo-project are in c:\projects\foo\
int blah;
```

(Strange errors for "undefined variable blah" occurs)

I would NEVER use line continuation in a single-line comment, but if you have some good reason to, just turn THAT warning off in MSVC.

Also as Mike says: Warnings are not even covered by the standard - it only says what needs to be an error. If you enable "warnings are errors", you will have to either be selective about what warnings you enable, or accept that some constructs that are technically valid (but dubious) will be unacceptable in the build, because the compiler maker has decided to warn about it. Try writing `if (c = getchar())` in gcc or clang and see how far you get with much -Werror and warnings on "high". Yet it is perfectly valid according to the standard.

Comment: From my reading of the standard, neither warnings or errors (as MSVC and gcc use them) are covered, only 'diagnostic messages' when the program violates any rule (unless one is not specifically required by the rule). In this case, your implementation can decide whether to try and produce the program even though it is ill-formed or give up. An error (in practical compiler terms) is a violation of a rule that the compiler decides it doesn't want to continue on, a warning is one that it does continue on.

Comment: I think the standard does not say HOW the compiler should deal with what is technically completely wrong (such as not declared variables, assigning a struct to an int variable, etc) - stop at the first error, try to continue, whatever, and whether you actually get a binary/object-file/executable or not from it. But warnings are situations that at best are covered as suggestions in the standard, certainly not "the code is invalid". Warnings are there to help the programmer avoid silly/common mistakes - so for example gcc insists on extra parenthesis in `if ((c = getchar())) ...`

Comment: Note that the point here is that you are enabling "Warning on Error". This implies you trust the compiler to be stricter about things that the standard accepts, but are (sometimes) causing problems. If you don't want that, then don't turn on warnings on errors. Or turn off the particular warnings that you think don't make sense [using `#pragma` you can do that over small sections of code, if you like]

Comment: I completely understand the reason for the warning, and in terms of practical development, I think it's good that it's there. The situations you pointed out could feasibly happen, and the warning would help diagnose them (mostly the first - the second would likely cause another error). My question was really about non-conformance of MSVC, which all the answers/comments seem to confirm that it's non-conformant, depending on the compile options - but gcc (and likely every other compiler) is as well.

Comment: I would argue that a compiler is only conformant with "treat warnings as errors" turned off [and some other options may need to be correctly set to ensure that the compiler "follows the standard"]. As my example with parenthesis around c = getchar() when used in an if-statement shows. That's CLEARLY correct code according to the standard, but not "flawless" when warnings are enabled.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a question of compliance. You've specifically asked the compiler to treat a valid construct as an error, so that's what it does.

GCC will give the same warning (or error, if requested) if you specify `-Wcomment` or `-Wall`.

Comment: I didn't give any additional flags to MSVC to actually generate the warning, this is just compiling with default options (except for /WX). I'm being extremely picky here, just because I'm curious. While I like having the ability to have -Werror + /WX, it seems like it lends itself to non-compliance, especially in cases where the code is actually compliant (assuming this code is). I've asked a follow up question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30438718/issue-warning-and-compiling-with-warnings-as-errors-violates-compliance.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito: _"If you have warnings as errors enabled (which, I do)"_